# Xampp x64-7.4.3-0-VC15 Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp

I have just installed xampp latest version but apache does not started showing error below. when i check it in console it shows error that 
**httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 74 of E:/xampp_7_4/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall it from E:/xampp_7_4 and install it G:/xampp. now its working fine. Main cause of above error is folder name xampp_7_4. It mean xampp should be install at root with folder name xampp